# Unable to get raycaster.intersectObjects() to return intersecting objects from a distance

Tags: three.js

I have a scatter plot with several random `Sprite` objects being used as data points.  I want to detect intersections between the mouse pointer (cursor) and `Sprite` objects.  The setup I am using to detect intersections is as follows:

```
var projector = new THREE.Projector();

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (ev) {
    if (ev.target == renderer.domElement) {
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3((ev.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1, -(ev.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1, 0.5);
        var projector = new THREE.Projector();
        projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(particles);
        console.log(intersects[0]);
    }
}, false);
```

The problem I am encountering is that when I click a `Sprite`object from a distance (i.e., click a data point and NOT zoomed in on the plot), nothing seems to be returned by `raycaster.intersectObjects(particles)`.  In other words, the length of `intersects`is 0.  The desired behavior is that when a data point is clicked (i.e., a data point appears under the cursor), `raycaster.intersectObjects()`returns the object under the cursor.

I have created a fiddle with what I've done thus far: http://jsfiddle.net/jmg157/ynFzw/

Many thanks, as always!

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem, and what is your question? Saying it does not "work correctly" is not descriptive.

Comment: For now, I'd like to be able to just detect when the user clicks on a point on the plot.  In other words, when the mouse pointer intersects a `Sprite` object.  Normally there would be an image used as a texture for the points.  The end goal is to have the user click a point and be able to query information about that point (i.e., coordinates, ID, etc.).  But for now just detecting when the pointer intersects a `Sprite` object would be awesome.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem -- or symptom? What is "not working"?

Comment: If you click on a point on the plot, the length of `intersects` seems to almost always be 0.  So it seems like the intersection between mouse pointer and data point is not registering correctly. The `intersects` array should hold the `Sprite` objects that intersect the mouse pointer.

Comment: Do the symptoms go away if you set `body { margin: 0px }` -- or are there still issues?

Comment: Still seem to have issues. I updated the fiddle with your suggestion though. Thanks for your help and for bearing with me on this.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44094/discussion-between-westlangley-and-androidnoobie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Raycaster`, you need to make sure in your CSS you set

```
body { margin: 0 }
```

or somethinhg equivalent, otherwise, detections will be offset.

Also, the `Raycaster` implementation for `Sprites` needs to be improved.

Currently, detection occurs if the ray passes within a certain distance of the sprite's position. The detection region is a circle of radius `sprite.scale.x`. The shape of the sprite is not considered.

three.js r.64

Comment: Wish I could buy you a beer.  Thank you again for your help.