# Raycasting and container in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, raycasting

I have been struggling with issues concerning **raycasting** on small **circlegeometries** on a **sphere**.

I know raycasting can't be done with **sprites** and this is why I use circlegeometries, but it doesn't work all the time, and moreover the raycasting doesn't always work on circles but sometimes around them as well.

Does anybody have an idea ? Here is a [JSBin to show you basically](http://jsbin.com/UQODecO/19/edit)

**Edit** : 
I updated my previous version of JSBin, you can click any circleGeometries it will work **[here](http://jsbin.com/UQODecO/29/edit)**, run it with output tab only open for better results

This is related to the renderer **width** and **height** properties, my sphere isn't in fullscreen and this is why it fails.

Does anybody have an idea on how to set up it right in order to get this to work perfectly ?

Comment: Update to three.js r.65 and try it with sprites. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823631/unable-to-get-raycaster-intersectobjects-to-return-intersecting-objects-from-a/20825975#20825975

Comment: I updated my version to 65 but I didn't try sprites as it actually doesn't fit my needs, I don't wanna have sprites colliding with the sphere, just pastilles around it. `Raycasting` doesn't work better :/

Comment: Use a debugger so you can track your errors. `objects` appears to be empty.

Comment: Updated the JSBin, `objects` contains 2 elements. I don't get why raycasting fails, this code is simple.

Comment: Your JSBin is using r.58... Sorry, I can't help you debug your code. But sep through it slowly with a debugger, and use the non-minified version of three.js r.66 -- `three.js` not `three.min.js`. You will figure out where things are going wrong.  Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula used to compute intersections wasn't the good one, here is the one that works :

```
    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

mouse x and y have slightly changed from the examples you can get, and are now fine.

```
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5);

    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(
            camera.position).normalize());

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(objects);

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you looking for some thing like this....Your code might need little changes... check this link http://jsfiddle.net/ebeit303/rjJ6q/

```
// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

// custom global variables
var targetList = [];
var projector, mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };

init();
animate();

// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{

    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // CAMERA
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 100000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(600,0,-1200);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
    // RENDERER

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // EVENTS

    // CONTROLS 

    // this material causes a mesh to use colors assigned to faces
    var faceColorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( 
    { color: 0xffffff, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } );

    var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 500, 64, 64 );
    for ( var i = 0; i < sphereGeometry.faces.length; i++ ) 
    {
        face = sphereGeometry.faces[ i ];   
        face.color.setRGB( 0, 0, 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2 );       
    }
    var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, faceColorMaterial );
    sphere.rotation.set(0, 14.5, 0);
    scene.add(sphere);

    //targetList.push(sphere);

    var j=0;

    for (var i =0; i<100;i+=5){
    //var circle = new THREE.CubeGeometry(5,5,5);
    var circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 8, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    //THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads(circle);
    var circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xDEF2EF});
    circleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(circle, circleMaterial);

    var Alon = i - 90;
    var Alat = j;

    var Aphi = Math.PI/2 - Alat * Math.PI / 180;
    var Atheta = 2 * Math.PI - Alon * Math.PI / 180;

    mesh.position.x = Math.sin(Aphi) * Math.cos(Atheta) * (501);
    mesh.position.y = Math.cos(Aphi) * (501);
    mesh.position.z = Math.sin(Aphi) * Math.sin(Atheta) * (501);    
    mesh.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    mesh.lookAt( sphere.position );

    sphere.add(mesh);
    targetList.push(mesh);

    j++;
    }


    // initialize object to perform world/screen calculations
    projector = new THREE.Projector();

    // when the mouse moves, call the given function
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

}

function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) 
{


    // update the mouse variable
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 )
    {       

        intersects[ 0 ].object.material.color.setRGB( 0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2,
                                                     0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2,
                                                     0.8 * Math.random() + 0.2 );
    }

}


function animate() 
{

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
}


function render() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: Actually, what did you change ?

Comment: don't insert the sphere mesh in the targetList array(Line no: 49)... don't forget to accept the answer if its useful..

Comment: Nice of you to take the time to reply but I know how to add & remove objects from the array used in raycasting. I'm rather looking for some maths to get my JS click to fit my canvas, even without being fullscreen.