# how to make objects hyperlink in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Below is my firstpage.js file.

```
 $(function(){

/*global variables*/
var scene, camera, renderer;
var spotLight, hemi;
var SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT;
var mouse
var loader, model, animation;
var objects = [];

function init(){


    /*creates empty scene object and renderer*/
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera =  new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(100, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, .1, 1000);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});

    renderer.setClearColor(0xEBE0FF);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled= true;
    renderer.shadowMapSoft = false;


    camera.position.x = -2;
    camera.position.y = 2;
    camera.position.z = -9; 
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    //hemi light
    hemi = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xbbbbbb, 0x660066);
    scene.add(hemi);        

    /*adds spot light with starting parameters*/
    spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight.castShadow = true;
    spotLight.position.set (20, 35, 40);
    scene.add(spotLight);

    //load blender scene
    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load("test.json",function ( obj ) {

        scene.add( obj );

        scene.traverse(function(children){
            objects.push(children);
        });                 
    });                
    $("#webGL-container").append(renderer.domElement);      
} 
 function render() { 
       scene.rotation.y += .005;       
}


function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();

$(window).resize(function(){
    SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    camera.aspect = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );
});

});
```

below is my firstpage.html file

```
<HTML>
<title> Demo Page</title>
<body>
<div id ="webGL-container" style="z-index:-9;"></div>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">     </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="three.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="firstpage.js"></script>        
</body>
</html>
```

how can i make each model a hyperlink and every model should redirect me to a new page.here test.json is a blender file which contains just 4 different characters.

Comment: Do you need it to be a real DOM <a/> hyperlink or would clicking on the model and providing the redirect suffice?

Comment: Can you tell me Both ways.@user01

Comment: Unless you have a fantastic reason to want <a> elements, the second method (raycasting) as briefly covered by Rush2112 is a much better solution. You can even emulate some of the things the make elements 'linky' by modifying your scene (highlight the model when hovered) or css changes (change the cursor from a pointer to a finger)

Answer (score 2):

First, you will need an eventListener for mouse clicks.

In that event listener, you setup a raycaster and see if any objects have been "clicked"

If they have, then you call `window.open(link)`

If you want each object to have their own link, then you would need to designate which object directs to which link.
Because raycaster returns an object, you can search through the list of children in the scene and hardcode if statements for each one

Example:
`if(raycaster.intersects[0] === object1) {
        window.open(link1)
} else if (raycaster.intersects[0] === object2 {
        window.open(link2)
}`

and so on

if you haven't used raycaster before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575208/raycasting-and-container-in-three-js) is a good example of how to set it up and use it

Comment: how am i gonna specify which 3dmodel is object1 and which one is object2.

Comment: [Object3D](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Core/Object3D), of which your models are composed, can be picked in several ways. They have `.name`, `.uuid`, or `.userData` to help you discern which

Comment: can you tell me any example or code where objects are selected using .uuid or userData @user01

Comment: thanks that really helped. i did it using if(intersects[0].object.name="name")

Comment: but window.open opens a new window i want to load it in the same window.

Comment: @sharadgupta Try [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_octree_raycasting), especially with how to modify the pointer on mouseover. ~ line 350 `intersections[ 0 ].object` has the first picked object. That will have .name and .uuid. Then you can test them like anything else is js (string test, regexp, etc). They just need to be set to something meaningful, probably when you export your scene. (ie 'puppy_obj' -> "puppy.org"

Answer (score 0):

3Dink.js is a wrapper library of three.js for WebGL that is enabled to make 3D hyperlinks easily. In this case, it is useful.

In the shortest case, It can realize click and cursor change in 3 lines.

```
DDDINK.addURL(object, "https://www.npmjs.com/package/3dink");
DDDINK.readRendererObj( renderer, scene, camera );
DDDINK.domEvent.addFnc();
```

Please browse it's repository. https://github.com/takashift/3Dink.js